# How can i hide password in inspect element?

Tags: php, html

i hope someone can help me.
I want  hide  parameter "value" in inspect element in input text where i show password with ****

```
<input class="form-control valid form-control-sm " placeholder="password" id="PASS" name="PASS" value="ciao" maxlength="200" type="password" >
```

the term in value is the password and i don't want to show it in inspect element.
thanks
(sorry for my english)

Comment: @Med he has already used `type="password"`

Comment: @Jordan, if you type in any password on the page the value attribute will not show the actual value in inspect element.

Comment: Why are you putting the password as the value of the input?! Usually, the user needs to input the value, passwords shouldn't be prefilled!

Comment: @TakitIsy after login if ip adress doesn't match with the  ip on my database i want recharge the login page with username and password prefilled  and another input for token